# FInding a value in an array consisting for 4 different classes

Tags: c#

This problem consists of 4 different classes. The problem is that:

1. The operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'.
2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'int'. This is in the min method.

It seems to me that the list[i] is what is specifically what I am needing to compare. If I remove the list[i] and replace it with `i` it just gives me 1000. If I remove `if (item.Equals(list[i]))` it gives me 0.

But I can add numbers to that integer and if the number is greater than the least (being 2) it recognizes or sees the number 2. That last part might not make a lot of sense and is hard to explain.

What or how can I compare to give me the minimum integer? Am I missing something small or is it something very big? Is list[i] what I am needing to even compare?

The problem I am still having is that when I try to do a compare, it is not recognizing T in comparison, and if I declare it in my class parameters that causes a lot of headache with the other classes (nor do I usually see IComparable in the class parameters)

I thought maybe

```
    public int min(ref T item)
    {
        int min = 1000;
        T tempItem = list[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].CompareTo(tempItem) < 0)
            {
                tempItem = list[i];
                min = i;
            }
        }
        item = tempItem;
        return min;

    }
```

Would work, but it still has not. The problem is being updated to more of a problem with CompareTo

```
    using System;

    namespace ArrayListNamespace
    {
      public abstract class ArrayList<T>
      {
        protected T[] list;
        protected int length;



        public ArrayList()
        {
            list = new T[100];
            length = 0;
        }

        public abstract void insert(ref T item);


        public int remove(ref T item)
        {
            if (length == 0) return 0;
            else
            {
                //find value, if it exists
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                    {
                        list[i] = list[length - 1];
                        length--;
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }
        public void print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
            }
        }
        public void removeAll(ref T item)
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                int r = remove(ref item);
                if (r == -1) break;
            }
        }
        public void removeAt(int location) //  probably can delete this
        {
            list[location] = list[length - 1];
            length--;
        }

        public int min(ref T item)
        {
            int min = 1000;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {

                    if (list[i] < min)
                    {
                        min = list[i];
                    }
            }
            return min;

        }
    }
}

     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using UnorderedArrayListNamespace;

     namespace test
       {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnorderedArrayList<int> u = new UnorderedArrayList<int>();
            u.print();
            int var = 5;
            u.insert(ref var);
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 12;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 2;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 29;
            u.insert(ref var);
            u.print();
            Console.WriteLine();
            var = 5;
            u.removeAll(ref var);
            u.print();

            Console.WriteLine("The min value is " + u.min(ref var));
        }
    }
}


     using System;

     namespace ArrayListADTNamespace
     {
    public interface ArrayListADT<T>
    {
        // insert() method places one item in the list
        void insert(ref T item);
        // remove() method removes first instance of item in list
        int remove(ref T item);
        // print() method prints all items in list
        void print();
        // removal all method
        void removeAll(ref T item);
        // min method
        int min(ref T item);
    }
}

    using System;
    using ArrayListNamespace;
    using ArrayListADTNamespace;

    namespace UnorderedArrayListNamespace
    {
    public class UnorderedArrayList<T> : ArrayList<T>, ArrayListADT<T>
    {
        public UnorderedArrayList()
        {
        }

        public override void insert(ref T item)
        {
            list[length] = item;
            length++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, you shouldn't need to pass values by `ref`.

Comment: Are you allowed to cheat and add a constraint on T as ValueType?

Comment: @ErikNoren and how would you propose he does that?

Comment: @ErikNoren I suppose I could. To the type parameter? I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @DanielA.White you are correct, I did not originally have that. That was some wild shot in the dark I added to test out if it would matter. This code has a lot of things I just "tested" to see if it would work. Ive put quite a bit of time into it

Comment: @DaveZych I had thought on public class UnorderedArrayList<T> : ArrayList<T>, ArrayListADT<T> he could add where T: ValueType but I admit I didn't actually try this to see if it would properly constrain T.

Comment: @ErikNoren the closest thing you could do is add a `where T: struct` constraint but that doesn't necessarily restrict it to value types nor does it restrict it to anything useful. You could still use a custom defined struct and break everything.

Comment: public class Array<T> : IList<T> where T: ValueType compiles. Unsure if it'll solve the problem which is why a comment and not answer.

Comment: I attempted that... and it has not solved it. Although I was hopeful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now (under the assumption that you are looking for the minimum value in the array) you are trying to compare an integer value to a variable of generic type T. This means that your array list may not hold values with types that are valid for comparison with int. What you'll want instead is something along the lines of

```
public int min(ref T item)
{
    int min = 1000;
    T tempItem = list[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].CompareTo(tempItem) < 0)
        {
            tempItem = list[i];
            min = i;
        }
    }
    item = tempItem;
    return min;

}
```

This way the item reference you passed in will hold the minimum item and the method will return the index of the minimum value.

If you want to just return the value of the item try this:

```
public T min( )
{
    T tempItem = list[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].CompareTo(tempItem) < 0)
        {
            tempItem = list[i];
        }
    }
    return tempItem;
}
```

Comment: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
I am wanting to compare T correct?

Comment: My mistake Azzamean, you need to ensure that T extends IComparable. See Michael's answer above. (I will also edit my own).

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that, in general, you are building a generic container class then making the assumption that everything in your class is an integer. Lets look at your `min` method:

```
public int min(ref T item)
{        
  int min = 1000;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (list[i] < min)
    {
      min = list[i];
    }
  }

  return min;
}
```

This makes sense if `T` is an numeric type, but what if you made an `UnorderedArrayList<string>` or `UnorderedArrayList<System.Uri>` or whatever? How would your `min` function possibly work? By making a type with a generic parameter you are telling the compiler "this class has to work with *every type that can ever be invented*", and the vast majority of those can neither be convert to nor compared with an int.

The quick answer is to replace

```
int min = 1000;
```

with

```
T min = default(T);
```

however, those two statements are obviously not identical. At the same time, it makes no sense to code a default minimum of 1000 into the method: if I give you a list of, say, "dog, cat, horse, cow, pig", is the minimum value of that list 1000?

The other thing to be aware of is that you are assuming the objects in your array can even be compared to each other, which is not a safe assumption. In order to enforce that, you need to do two things:

1. Constrain your type to be comparable:

   ```
   public abstract class ArrayList<T> where T : IComparable
   ```
2. Use `IComparable`'s methods instead of the operators:

   ```
   if (list[i].CompareTo(min) < 0)
   {
     min = list[i];
   }
   ```